# How to run c++ in atom with the atom script package?

Tags: c++, atom-editor

I have a windows 10 computer with atom version 1.52.0 and g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0. I can run c++ programs in Atom with the gpp-compiler, but I don't like how the program output is in a new window rather than at the bottom of the Atom window. I'm trying to set up c++ with the script package, but when I run the program with the script package I get the following error.

```
g++: error: /mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/USACO/2015-2016/December/Silver/test.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I can run java programs with the script package btw. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DkEz.png)

Comment: Are you using WSL or some other reason for the `/mnt/c`?

Comment: not sure what WSL means (World Surf League?), so probably not. what do you mean by "reason for the /mnt/c? i also don't know that /mnt/c means either.

Comment: Windows subsystem for linux. Allows you to run linux under windows. On WSL paths like /mnt/c exists and allow the linux OS to use files in the windows filesystem

Comment: alright, i get what WSL and /mnt/c are, but why would I need them? That is, why do I need to run Linux under windows? I just wanna run c++ programs?

Comment: My point is your settings seem to be setup for WSL and not windows. I am not sure why. I use Visual Studio Community primarily and sometimes Qt-Creator or VSCode. I  can't possibly understand all code editors / IDEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late to reply. But for those to come here from Google, on the [script package page](https://atom.io/packages/script), it clearly says:

```
+---------+------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Grammer | File Based | Selection Based | Required Package |  Required in PATH  |                          Notes                          |
+---------+------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| C++     | Yes        | Yes             |                  | xcrun clang++/g++  | Available only on macOS and Linux. Run with -std=c++14. |
+---------+------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

*Available only on **macOS** and **Linux**. Run with `-std=c++14`.*

So, it seems it's not available for Windows. Instead, you can use another package called `gpp-compiler`:
https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler

It works fine on windows:

> You'll need to install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and [add it to your PATH](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/).

Comment: yup that's what I ended up doing! the gpp-compiler package works and runs c++ fine.